# Delete and Replace a button in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've integrated data Tables in my project and its work is fantastic but now since I don't need the number of entries [filter] and so I have removed it by using

```
   display:none
```

in my style sheet and now what I need is that I don't know how to move the "Add New" button to the place of the entry filter [in the below image]. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.....

[image]

Comment: where is the place that you want in that image...

Comment: Without knowing the page structure,it would be difficult to say.

Comment: what do mean by placing the button to the place filter, can you be more specific

Comment: after removing entries what do you have in your page?! how does it look like?!

Comment: if you are using jquery, then use $(idOfButton).css(property: value); for example you want to locate that button on the right... use $(idOfButton).css("float":"right"); something like that.. or you provide some more details

Comment: I first thought you were using the JQuery DataTables Plugin, but it doesn't incude a "Add New" button. What exactly are you using? If the button is added manually by you, you can add it wherever you want in DOM, and your code is important for understanding your problem, can you JSFiddle it?

Comment: Sorry guys it took me some time to return back.... Actually I need the add new button in the place of filter(in that image)... The button is not from datatables and hence i dont know to integrate the button in replacing the entry filter...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the [JQuery DataTables Plugin](http://www.datatables.net).

**1 - Removing the Length Selector**

To remove the number of entries selector, you should configure the  DOM elements/positioning accordingly, which avoids adding instead of just hiding some elements. The plugin has an example:

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/dom.html

The `sDom` docs:

http://datatables.net/ref#sDom

The first thing you need to do is to remove the "l" from `sDom: "lfrtip"` (if bJQueryUI is false) or `sDom: '<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>'` (if bJQueryUI is true), which means you'd remove the length select widget.

**2 - Placing another widget where the Length Selector would be placed**

That's about the CSS. I'm assuming your new widget is placed just before the data table. This would allow floats from before:

```
div.dataTables_wrapper { clear: none; }
```

The search edit input is a `float: right;` and the table has a `clear: both;` by default. So you can make your add button a `float: left;`, and that should solve your problem.

See the [jsfiddle I've done with that](http://jsfiddle.net/djsbellini/8YWgE/).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer H.D. But My question is still not answered... I've deleted the length select widget but all i need to know is how to place a simple button which is not related to datatables in the place where the filter existed?.

Comment: That's what the `float: left;` should do. I changed the answer to be more explicit, and added a needed clearing (by default, there's a `clear: both;` in `.dataTables_wrapper`).

Comment: No changes happened .. you can view the current structure of my page in the answer i posted.....I dont know wat to do.... Being a headache here

Answer (score 0):

Now it looks like this after adding

```
 float:left
```

[image]

Comment: There's something clearing the floats, perhaps the CSS is missing the `.dataTables_wrapper` part. You can also try `div.dataTables_wrapper { clear: none; }` using the "div" to be more specific, instead of just the class name. I changed my answer accordingly. Please add this information to your question, instead of adding it as a new answer.

Comment: I've added a working example now as a JSFiddle link in my answer. If that's not enough, I really need more information to be able to help you.